# Can i create a R function with text input for plotting

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have to make several similar ggplots using different data frames.

Is there a way to make a function with text input in style with the following:

```
ManData = function(x){
  ggplot(data=x,aes(x=Treatment,y=value))+
  geom_point()
}
```

The data.frames and plots I am working with are much more detailed, but this illustrates the problem I struggle with. I could plot it all manually, but this would shorten the code and make my life easier.

Thanks in advance!

EDIT - So apparently simplifying things made me find my mistake, script now works.

But how can I add labels based on the function input.

Say:

```
ManPlot = function(x){
  ggplot(x,aes(x=Treatment,y=value))+
    geom_point()+
    labs(tag = "x")+
    theme(plot.tag.position = c(0.75,0.5))
}
```

This returns an x as label instead of the input. Without the "" I get the entire data frame labelled across the plot. Thanks.

Comment: did you try out your example?  Did it work?

Comment: It did not work the other day, but it seems to work right now. I think it stops working when I start adding labels also. Sorry - editing post to an example that I know does not work.

Comment: @dww updated it, sorry.

Comment: What do you want the tag to be? To get the name of the variable passed to ManPlot, try `tag=deparse(substitute(x))`

Comment: @KentJohnson thank you, that worked. Thought I had already tried it - must have messed up someone else when I did...